# Error in calling cross_validation in sklearn - "unexpected keyword argument 'n_splits"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, spyder

Here is the code:

```
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC()))
# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
for name, model in models:
    kfold = cross_validation.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = cross_validation.cross_val_score(model, X_train, Y_train, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

Which produces this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 13, in 
    kfold = cross_validation.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_splits'

Answer (score 0):

```
`cross_validation.KFold`
```

does not have keyword n_splits ([see documentation](http://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html)). It uses `k` instead. If you want to have `n_splits` keyword, you may use `sklearn.model_selection.KFold` instead ([see here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)).

Comment: Thanks. I started with model_selection; but that requires scikit-learn 0.18.1.  When I tried to update scikit-learn in Anaconda, it says I do not have permission, even though I am logged in as administrator.

Comment: Then try to do kfold = cross_validation.KFold(n=...,k=10), where n= your total number of elements.